# ng build --aot with out prod mode is not compiling in AOT

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

Can we use this AOT mode for dev or qa mode by passing --aot flags in ng build command like "ng build --env=dev --aot". Actually I have tried but its not compiling with 'AOT'? Could any one suggest some solution?

Comment: Could you provide more information? What error are you getting?

Comment: There was no error. Its just compiling in normal JIT and bundle files generated under dist folder

Comment: Yes the `--aot` flag is working well.

Comment: when I build using ng build --prod the dist size is small , but the same using --aot flag the size is comparatively high

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by adding this flag

```
ng build --aot=true
```

the default value for --aot is false. (in non prod environments)

You can see more detail for the build options here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md

Comment: Thanks. ya Agree,but its with out minified. Can we minify as well using ng build? official docs says we cant do Minification using angular-cli.